# GeoServer 2.10.0 - How to use CreateStoredQuery

Tags: geoserver, wfs, inspire

I need to create the **GetSpatialDataSet** stored query in my WFS service to follow the INSPIRE rules.

That WFS service is in a GeoServer 2.10.0. I have checked the official docs about how to create a stored query: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html

The problem is I don't know what I am supposed to do with that piece of code.

```
<wfs:CreateStoredQuery service='WFS' version='2.0.0'
 xmlns:wfs='http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0'
 xmlns:fes='http://www.opengis.org/fes/2.0'
 xmlns:gml='http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2'
 xmlns:myns='http://www.someserver.com/myns'
 xmlns:topp='http://www.openplans.org/topp'>
<wfs:StoredQueryDefinition id='myStoredQuery'>
<wfs:Parameter name='AreaOfInterest' type='gml:Polygon'/>
<wfs:QueryExpressionText
 returnFeatureTypes='topp:states'
 language='urn:ogc:def:queryLanguage:OGC-WFS::WFS_QueryExpression'
 isPrivate='false'>
  <wfs:Query typeNames='topp:states'>
    <fes:Filter>
      <fes:Within>
        <fes:ValueReference>the_geom</fes:ValueReference>
         ${AreaOfInterest}
      </fes:Within>
    </fes:Filter>
  </wfs:Query>
</wfs:QueryExpressionText>
```

Where should I paste it? It says it's a POST request, but that doesn't tell me anything.

EDIT: I have tried the following script from another answer:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>WFS Test</title>
<script language="JavaScript">
  function doit()
  {
    var url = 'http://myserver:8080/geoserver/test/wfs';
    var method = 'POST';
    var postData = '<wfs:CreateStoredQuery\n'
    + 'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"\n'
    + 'xsi:schemaLocation=\n'
    + '"http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0\n'
    + 'http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd"\n'
    + 'xmlns:cp_inspire="urn:x-
inspire:specification:gmlas:CadastralParcels:4.0"\n'
    + 'xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.org/fes/2.0"\n'
    + 'xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0"\n'
    + 'xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"\n'
    + 'xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"\n'
    + 'service="WFS"\n'
    + 'version="2.0.0">\n'
    + '<wfs:StoredQueryDefinition\n'
    + 'id=\'' + 
'http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/operation/download/GetSpatialDataSet' + '\'>\n'
    + '<wfs:Parameter name=\'' + 'CRS' + '\' type=\'' + 'xsd:string' + '\'/>\n'
    + '<wfs:Parameter name=\'' + 'DataSetIdCode' + '\' type=\'' + 'xsd:string' +'\'/>\n'
    + '<wfs:Parameter name=\'' + 'DataSetIdNamespace' + '\' type=\'' + 'xsd:string' +'\'/>\n'
    + '<wfs:Parameter name=\'' + 'Language' + '\' type=\'' + 'xsd:string' + '\'/>\n'
    + '<wfs:Parameter name="count" type="xsd:integer"></wfs:Parameter>\n'
    + '<wfs:QueryExpressionText\n'
    + 'returnFeatureTypes=\'' + 'cp_inspire:CP.CadastralParcel' + '\'\n'
    + 'language=\'' + 'urn:ogc:def:queryLanguage:OGC-WFS::WFS_QueryExpression' + '\'\n'
    + 'isPrivate=\'' + 'false' + '\'>\n'
    + '<wfs:Query typeNames=\'' + 'cp_inspire:CP.CadastralParcel' + '\' srsName="${CRS}">\n'
    + '</wfs:Query>\n'
    + '</wfs:QueryExpressionText>\n'
    + '</wfs:StoredQueryDefinition>\n'
    + '</wfs:CreateStoredQuery>\n';

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", url, true);
req.setRequestHeader('User-Agent', 'XMLHTTP/1.0');
req.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'test/xml');
req.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (req.readyState != 4) return;
  if (req.status != 200 && req.status != 304) {
    alert('HTTP error ' + req.status);
    return;
  }
  alert(req.responseText);
}
if (req.readyState == 4) return;
req.send(postData);
```

}

But I'm getting this error:

[image]

Does anyone see where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

See the following post on INSPIRE Thematic Clusters: [It seems that there is only one fully compliant solution to serve multiple harmonised datasets trough WFS 2.0](https://themes.jrc.ec.europa.eu/discussion/view/88206/it-seems-that-there-is-only-one-fully-compliant-solution-to-serve-multiple-harmonised-datasets-trough-wfs-20?offset=30)

It appears that your problem is related to a [bug in GeoServer](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-5512) fixed in version 2.12-beta.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's a bug I will face later. In my request I'm using just one Type Name, so I don't think it's the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I modified your request a bit to use JQUERY and test with the data I had available, but this one seemed to work:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>WFS Test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    Press this button to create a stored Query with the parameters<br>
    <input type="button" value="doit" onclick="doit()"/>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        function doit() {
            $.ajax({ type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://myserver:8080/geoserver/wfs?',
                data: '<wfs:CreateStoredQuery service="WFS" version="2.0.0"'
                        + ' xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0"'
                        + ' xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0"'
                        + ' xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.org/fes/2.0"'
                        + ' xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1"'
                        + ' xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">'
                        + '<wfs:StoredQueryDefinition id="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/operation/download/GetSpatialDataSet">'
                        + '<wfs:Title>Stored Query for hy-n:WatercourseLink</wfs:Title>'
                        + '<wfs:Parameter name="CRS" type="xsd:string" />'
                        + '<wfs:Parameter name="DataSetIdCode" type="xsd:string" />'
                        + '<wfs:Parameter name="DataSetIdNamespace" type="xsd:string" />'
                        + '<wfs:Parameter name="Language" type="xsd:string" />'
                        + '<wfs:Parameter name="count" type="xsd:integer" />'
                        + '<wfs:QueryExpressionText returnFeatureTypes="hy-n:WatercourseLink" language="urn:ogc:def:queryLanguage:OGC-WFS::WFS_QueryExpression" isPrivate="false">'
                        + '<wfs:Query typeNames="hy-n:WatercourseLink" srsName="${CRS}">'
                        + '</wfs:Query>'
                        + '</wfs:QueryExpressionText>'
                        + '</wfs:StoredQueryDefinition>'
                        + '</wfs:CreateStoredQuery>',
                contentType: "text/xml",
                dataType: "text",
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    console.log(xhr.status);
                    console.log(thrownError);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

You may encounter some additional namespace issues, depending on your GeoServer workspaces.

Once it works, you can use other commands like

```
http://myserver:8080/geoserver/wfs?request=ListStoredQueries&version=2.0.0&service=WFS
```

to see all your Stored Queries,

```
http://myserver:8080/geoserver/wfs?request=DescribeStoredQueries& storedQuery_Id=http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/operation/download/GetSpatialDataSet
```

to show associated Metadata or

```
http://myserver:8080/geoserver/wfs?request=DropStoredQuery&storedQuery_Id=http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/operation/download/GetSpatialDataSet
```

to drop the element again.